Temperature of plasma sputtering magnetron
This question is in regards to DC magnetron sputtering for coating surfaces. My main goal is to determine how much heat will be seen by the anode, cathode and the target. As well as to determine what material I should use to insulate the anode and cathode from each other.
Assumptions: Voltage : 450 V DC
Current : 1 mA to 1 Amp
My question is,

What temperature rating should the insulator between the anode and cathode have?
What temperature should the anode, cathode and target be rated for given the above voltage/current specs?

My attempt to answer this: Most of the plasma heat should be dissipated on the target itself (which will be water cooled). So as long as the water cooling is sufficient, then the target heat should be managed.
But I don't know how hot to estimate the anode will get (since this is not water cooled). I also don't know what temperature rating the insulator between the anode and cathode should be (any recommendations on materials would be greatly appreciated).

The systems I know of use ceramic insulators where you will melt the other components before you impact the insulator. Could you clarify? And don't discount just how hot your samples get...

Do you have a part or image to share of such a ceramic insulator? Right now, I am trying to determine specifications for parts, I don't have anything built yet.

Been a long time. Usually the vacuum chamber is ground (better be for your safety). The sputter gun is mounted on it, with the chamber as ground reference. Any insulation that supports biasing the sputter gun is within that unit. Similarly, if the sample holder/platen can be biased relative to the chamber, its mounting will have appropriate insulators to hold off those voltages. Frankly, neither should be subject to high temperatures. Macor should be just fine, and is a nice machinable ceramic.

@jon custer, were you a thin film guy in a previous epoch?

Thin films, CVD, ion beams, CMOS, MEMS, materials, ...

@JonCuster Yowza! who did you work for???

@Jon , Macor products give me a good point of reference on what to use as far an insulating material. Thank you!  Also thank you for the pointers for using the vac chamber as a ground reference.

@jon custer, Understood!! Colorado, or palo alto?
